# execute a workflow on multiple list items automatically even the items are not changed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Can a workflow automatically execute for all items that will meet the criteria even if the items are not modified anymore?

My logic is:

All items in List A that are closed, and aging >50 days should be copied to List B and then deleted in List A.

I cannot figure out how to setup a workflow for it.

*I have a column for closed/open and aging

Comment: I think you need a timer job

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily by using timer job. Create a timer job which will run on daily basis, write condition to check List A items age like, today - created date if it's more than 50 take that SPListItemCollection and do foreach on it to move to List B. Delete collection post successful movement to List B.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the information management policy in the list settings.  You should be able to execute a workflow based on age.  You may have to tweak settings in central admin, I think the timer job for that runs once per week by default, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You do need an information management policy (which is neither as difficult as it sounds, nor as time consuming as a timer job).

First off, you could take a look at this article on information management policy: https://www.dynamics101.com/sharepoint-information-management-policy/

You need to do the following:

1. Create a policy for your list
2. There should be a retention stage at the `Created date + 50 days` (to represent aging)
3. This rention stage then triggers a workflow - which you create in SP Designer.
4. Now since the workflow requires to run only if the list item is "Closed", you need to add a condition in the first step of workflow.

Now coming to the scenario where `Created Date + 50 days` is not the "Aging" for your list. You can then create a retention stage that is repeated every day (instead of running after 50 days) and then your workflow can validate the aging value as well (in addition to closed/open), and if both validations pass, further workflow activities are carried out. Basically your workflow will run everyday checking if the aging is 50 days and the item is closed. And for any item that matches, further activities will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

finally with some work around I achieved the same,

while creating first task, I made it available for both groups[ group 1 and group 2]. if any one approves it will go for approval from group 3 so fro group 3 there is a task now. what about the group which is not approved in first level any ways its optional but we need that group approval to settle request finally. As soon as first task got approved I am creating task for both group 3 and group 2[if group 1 approved in this case]. for group 3 in the same task list and extra task in another task list. another task list of same structure as like main one.